# ¿Como ordenar un array multidimensional con javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

tengo este array multidimensional, y estoy tratando de ordenar con el indice "nombre", he intentado con la funcion sort() pero no funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien he intentado esto pero tampoco funciona, el array que intento ordenar se llama result.

```
var x = $scope.result.sort(function(a,b){return a[0][1] > b[0][1] ? 1 : -1;});
```

es posible ordenarlo de tal manera que queden en orden alfabético del nombre?
es decir primero el "aaa", luego "bbbb", y así sucesivamente.

Comment: En el query donde mandas llamar todos esos datos deberia poner al final `ORDER BY nombre ASC`

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, estos datos no vienen de una base de datos.

Comment: esos se conocen como array de objetos, no  multidimensional

Comment: @JackNavaRow Tienes razón en parte: Tiene un array de un elemento, que es un array de 4 elementos. Así que el array externo ya está ordenado

Comment: @pablo-lozano gracias por su apreciación, me queda mas claro ahora

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puede intentar con:

```
objs.sort(function(a, b){ return a.nombre > b.nombre ? 1 : b.nombre > a.nombre ? -1 : 0 });
```

ó con expresiones de funciones flecha:

```
objs.sort((a, b) => a.first_nom > b.first_nom ? 1 :  b.first_nom > a.first_nom ? -1 : 0);
```

Tambien puedes usar la funcion [`localCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/localeCompare):

```
objs.sort((a, b) => a.nombre.localeCompare(b.nombre));
```

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, tus soluciones fueron de gran ayuda para resolver mi problema, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2):

Suponiendo que tu es un arreglo de arreglos de la siguiente forma:

```
var array = [
    [
        { id: 0, nombre: "ccc" },
        { id: 1, nombre: "bbb" },
        { id: 2, nombre: "ddd" },
        { id: 3, nombre: "aaa" }
    ],
    [
        { id: 4, nombre: "hhh" },
        { id: 5, nombre: "eee" },
        { id: 6, nombre: "fff" },
        { id: 7, nombre: "ggg" }
    ]
];
```

Puedes iterar los primeros elementos con la función `forEach` y enseguida utilizar la función `sort()` para ordenarlos.

```
var newArray = [];
array.forEach(elemento => {
    newArray.push(elemento.sort((a, b) => a.nombre < b.nombre ? -1 : a.nombre > b.nombre ? 1 : 0));
});
console.log(newArray);
```

Aquí el ejemplo completo:

```js
var array = [
    [
        { id: 0, nombre: "ccc" },
        { id: 1, nombre: "bbb" },
        { id: 2, nombre: "ddd" },
        { id: 3, nombre: "aaa" }
    ],
    [
        { id: 4, nombre: "hhh" },
        { id: 5, nombre: "eee" },
        { id: 6, nombre: "fff" },
        { id: 7, nombre: "ggg" }
    ]
];
var newArray = [];
array.forEach(elemento => {
    newArray.push(elemento.sort((a, b) => a.nombre < b.nombre ? -1 : a.nombre > b.nombre ? 1 : 0));
});
console.log(newArray);
```

#### Referencias

1. [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)
2. [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach)