# Ordenar los datos despues de filtrar

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Esta es otra parte de mis andanzas con los scripts de google, en la última pregunta [¿Cómo filtrar un Array 2D usando dos criterios de coincidencia exacta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/238667/c%C3%B3mo-filtrar-un-array-2d-usando-dos-criterios-de-coincidencia-exacta/238991?noredirect=1#comment445416_238991) pensé que tenía terminado el script, pero luego se me ocurrió poder ordenar el array para que me enseñe los datos en el orden que yo quiera, la intención es poner varios criterios para ordenar y que se ejecuten de manera secuencial.

El script que tengo es este:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var range = e.range;
  var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex(); //Same as getColumn()
  var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex(); //Same as getRow()

  //Donde utilizar el filtro
  var rangeLlista = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Llista").getRange("A6:AX500").getValues();

  //Lo que queremos borrar
  var rangeBorrar = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Asignacion").getRange("A9:AX500");

  //Asignacion de las celdas que tiene que filtrar.
  var RangeAsignacion = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Asignacion").getRange("A2:F2");

  //Los criterios a filtrar
  var Asignacion1 = RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,2).getValue().toString();
  var Asignacion2 = RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,5).getValue().toString();

  //Columna de los criterios a filtrar, la culumna A = 0
  var columnIndex1 = 5;
  var columnIndex2 = 6;

  //Mira si se modifican las celas que nosotros queremos
  if(range.getSheet().getName() === 'Asignacion'){

    var watchRange1 = {
      top : 2, // start row
      bottom : 2, // end row
      left : 1, // start col
      right : 6, // end col
    };

    if(colIndex >= watchRange1.left && colIndex <= watchRange1.right && rowIndex >= watchRange1.top && rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && e.Value != 0){

      //Borrado del contenido anterior
      /*var start = 9;
      var end = rangeBorrar.getMaxRows();

      rangeBorrar.deleteRows(start, end - start);*/

      rangeBorrar.clear({contentsOnly: true});

      //Se realiza el filtrado
      var filteredData = rangeLlista.filter(function (dataRow){

        return dataRow[columnIndex1] === Asignacion1 && dataRow[columnIndex2] === Asignacion2;

      });

      var rows = filteredData.length;
      var columns = filteredData[0].length;
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(9,1,rows,columns).setValues(filteredData);

    };

  };

};
```

Esto es lo que estoy intentando:

```
var filteredData = rangeLlista.filter(function (dataRow).sort(19,true){ return dataRow[columnIndex1] === Asignacion1 && dataRow[columnIndex2] === Asignacion2; });
```

Dejo un enlace a un documento de pruebas:

[Doc pruebas](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QNEp9-b-UUyRnFtNmpnbFigJW0O6_tvzUTRloaeG7Bc/edit?usp=sharing)

Esto es lo que tengo ahora mismo:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var range = e.range;
  var colIndex = range.getColumnIndex(); //Same as getColumn()
  var rowIndex = range.getRowIndex(); //Same as getRow()

  //Donde utilizar el filtro
  var rangeLlista = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Llista").getRange("A6:AX500");

  //Lo que queremos borrar
  var rangeBorrar = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Asignacion").getRange("A9:AX500");

  //Asignacion de las celdas que tiene que filtrar.
  var RangeAsignacion = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Asignacion").getRange("A2:F2");

  //Los criterios a filtrar
  var Asignacion1 = RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,2).getValue().toString();
  var Asignacion2 = RangeAsignacion.getCell(1,5).getValue().toString();

  //Columna de los criterios a filtrar, la culumna A = 0
  var columnIndex1 = 5;
  var columnIndex2 = 6;

  //Mira si se modifican las celas que nosotros queremos
  if(range.getSheet().getName() === 'Asignacion'){

    var watchRange1 = {
      top : 2, // start row
      bottom : 2, // end row
      left : 1, // start col
      right : 6, // end col
    };

    if(colIndex >= watchRange1.left && colIndex <= watchRange1.right && rowIndex >= watchRange1.top && rowIndex <= watchRange1.bottom && e.Value != 0){


      rangeBorrar.clear({contentsOnly: true});

      //La columna 19 es la T
      rangeLlista.sort([{column: 19, ascending: true},{column: 16, ascending: true},{column: 17, ascending: true},{column: 18, ascending: true},{column: 2, ascending: true},{column: 3, ascending: true},{column: 4, ascending: true}]);

      var llista = rangeLlista.getValues();

      //Se realiza el filtrado
      var filteredData = llista.filter(function (dataRow){

        return dataRow[columnIndex1] === Asignacion1 && dataRow[columnIndex2] === Asignacion2;

      });

      var rows = filteredData.length;
      var columns = filteredData[0].length;
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(9,1,rows,columns).setValues(filteredData);

    };

  };

};
```

Las 2 primeras columnas me las filtra bien, pero el resto no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He resuelto el problema modificando estas lineas:

```
//La columna 20 es la T
      rangeLlista.sort([{column: 20, ascending: true},{column: 17, ascending: true},{column: 18, ascending: true},{column: 19, ascending: true},{column: 2, ascending: true},{column: 3, ascending: true},{column: 4, ascending: true}]);

      var llista = rangeLlista.getValues();
```

Tenia un fallo diciendo que columnas eran

Answer (score 2):

Básicamente tienes dos alternativas

1. Usar un método propio de Google Apps Script
2. Usar métodos de JavaScript

---

## Método propio de Google Apps Script

Class Range incluye el método [sort(sortSpecObj)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj). A continuación el ejemplo de la documentación oficial con los comentarios traducidos

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C7");

// Ordena por los valores en la primer columna (A)
range.sort(1);

// Ordena por los valores en la segunda columna (B)
range.sort(2);

// Ordena de forma descendiente por columna B
range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false});

//  Ordena de forma descendiente por columna B, luego ascendente por columna A
// Note the use of an array
range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: false}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);

// Para filas que son ordenadas en forma ascendente, el parámetro ascendente
// es opcional, se puede usar sólo un entero con la columna. Observe que en
// en general, mantener la especificación de ordenado resulta en código más
// fácil de leer. El ordenado anterior se puede expresar de la siguiente forma:
range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: false}, 1]);

// Como alternativa, si quieres todas las columna en orden ascendente, puedes usar
// lo siguiente (esto hace la columna 2 ascendente)
range.sort([2, 1]);
// ... lo que es equivalente a
range.sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}, {column: 1, ascending: true}]);
```

## Usar métodos de JavaScript

Preguntas relacionadas

- [¿Como ordenar un array multidimensional con javascript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/224771/65)

Comment: Estoy utilizando esto `var rangeLlista = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Llista").getRange("A6:AX500").sort([{column: 19, ascending: true},{column: 16, ascending: true},{column: 17, ascending: true},{column: 18, ascending: true},{column: 2, ascending: true},{column: 3, ascending: true},{column: 4, ascending: true}]).getValues();`pero no parece que filtre bien

Comment: @IvánMontero lee con atención el ejemplo y si hay algo de este que no entiendas pregunta.

Comment: Pues no se que es lo que no estoy entendiendo

Comment: @IvánMontero En el ejemplo de la respuesta ¿Cuántas líneas de código tienen var, sort y getValues en la misma línea?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta ¿Cuántas lineas de código tiene en la misma línea? Me suena redundante, a que te refieres?

Comment: @IvánMontero Por favor lee de nuevo la pregunta de mi comentario previo.